# Error build VSTS - VSTest TASK - OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: selenium, build, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

I'm still trying to run my tests as integration continues in VSTS, however, a bug is being presented in the build:

[error] OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: can not find Chrome binary

I'm running the build on the agent HOSTED VS2017 and in the details of it, says that it has Chrome installed. However, there is an error when attempting to execute.

Anyone know if there's any other way?

Comment: I did not get help so far. I really had to build a build server and install the chromedriver. Then it worked on my machine.

Comment: Kindly post this comment in the answer and accept it in case it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to build a build server and install the chromedriver. Then it worked on my machine